# Templates: Passing the arguments in a template as arguments

Tags: c++, function, templates

In [the *Infinite Skills* "Advanced C++ Programming Training Video"](http://www.infiniteskills.com/training/advanced-c-plus-plus-programming.html), in a section about function templates, the presenter said that while passing the arguments to such function, we need to pass them by references and not by values as it might result in compiler giving us a "hard time". I have no idea about what this could be. The function calculates the maximum value of the two arguments and returns the same. The two functions are as follows:

```
// The function given in the tutorial
T maxVal(T &a1, T &a2)
{
    if(a1<a2)
        return a1;
    else
        return a2;
}

// My function
T maxVal(T a1, T a2)
{
    if(a1<a2)
        return a1;
    else
        return a2;
}
```

The problem is that both of the seem to work fine. Could you please help me by telling what are possible "hard times" that I can get ?

Comment: Perhaps unnecessary copies (though the first one you've shown won't accept temporaries and should take by const reference).

Comment: You could have hard times with the first example if you pass a temporary. This leads me to conclude the tutorial is not very good.

Comment: Is the tutorial a secret?

Comment: My reasoning for the tutorial not being good is stating something and backing it up with "it's magic".

Comment: Is that the only problem that might arise ? I thought that passing by value is bad but that doesn't mean that we should use passing by reference all the time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am sorry. Its http://www.infiniteskills.com/training/advanced-c-plus-plus-programming.html .

Comment: So, by using this line of logic, I should be returning a reference as well. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first taking a non const reference will not support: max(1, 2);
The second taking arguments by value will copy the argument: max(huge_object_a, huge_object_b); // The compiler might optimize, though.

`std::max` is:

```
template <class T> const T& max(const T& a, const T& b);
```

Comment: So, all this is about avoiding the creation of copies which are results of passing by values, right?